# Kubernetes cluster through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, kubernetes

I have multiples nodes spread accross differents locations and i would like to use them in a kubernetes cluster (k3s) throught OpenVPN.

Has anyone already tried this and could give me some leads ?

Thanks,

So far i experienced issues with nodes talking with each others.

Comment: The question is overly generic, but a good start is https://readthedocs.vinczejanos.info/Blog/2023/04/21/install-kube-tailscale/#